# disable back navigation after logout

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an app that uses a base StackNavigator which has one route that is a TabNavigator and one of the tabs is a StackNavigator.

```
const profileStack = StackNavigator({
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },      
  ...
})

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Trending: { screen: TrendingScreen },
  Notifications: { screen: NotificationsScreen },
  ProfileTab: { screen: profileStack }
})

const NavigatedApp = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  ...,
  Tabs: { screen: Tabs },
})
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to logout from the profileStack which navigates to Login and doesn't allow the back action, which goes back into the profileStack.

Most all of the answers I'm finding are using the reset action in one way or another. The most relevent I found was to reset the profileStack and then navigate to the main stack.

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [ NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Settings' })]
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })
```

However if I reset the profileStack and then navigate to the main stack (Login), the back action still takes me back to the profileStack, but I need the back action to exit the app instead of taking the user back into the reset profileStack.

Comment: You should use `SwitchNavigator`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html#exitapp).

In a possible `LoginScreen` component, you will want to adjust two lifecycle hooks similarly:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  // ...

  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
      BackHandler.exitApp()
      return true
    }.bind(this))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress')
  }

  // ...
}
```